# Select one non NA from multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, na

Surprised this hasn't been asked before (as far as I can see)

I have a data.frame with multiple columns and two rows, such as the below.

```
df<-as.data.frame(rbind(row1=c(NA,NA,rep(0,2),"FOO",NA,"BAR","FOO","FOOBAR","ETC"),
                   row2=c(300,23.4,1,2,"BAR","FOO","BAR","HELLO","WORLD","ETC")))
```

I want to select the entry in the first row as default but only if it's not `NA`. If it is `NA` I want to entry in the second row. I've tried the following:

```
apply(df,2,function(x) ifelse(is.na(x[1]),x[2],x[1]))
```

However, x is a combination of numeric and character and each columns class needs to be maintained so apply is causing issues. Also I need it returned as a data frame and not a named vector.

Comment: Your apply function should be: (df,2,function(x) ifelse(is.na(x[1]),x[2],x[1]))

Comment: Good spot, have fixed the question.

Comment: Well, the dataframe shared has all the columns as factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if this is what you are after.

```
df<-as.data.frame(rbind(row1=c(NA,NA,rep(0,2),"FOO",NA,"BAR","FOO","FOOBAR","ETC"),
                        row2=c(300,23.4,1,2,"BAR","FOO","BAR","HELLO","WORLD","ETC")))


outDF <- lapply(df, function(x){
  if(is.na(x[[1]])&!is.na(x[[2]])){
    x[[1]] <- x[[2]]
  }
  x
})
data.frame(outDF, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```